# Should I try to get rid of "Inappropriate ioctl for device" in strace output for a Bash script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, io

I'm using `strace` with this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

exec 0<test.log
while IFS= read -r line; do
    printf "%s\n" "$line"
done
```

(The straight `<test.log` redirection gives the same result.)

I'm getting this error for each read line:

```
ioctl(0, TCGETS, 0x7fff1e645d50)        = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
```

I've done some research and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1605533/6631810) is the nearest answer. It's far from being spot-on though. My script works fine, I'm just wondering if this is something I should deal with or just the standard way of Bash. Isn't it striking that the `ioctl` function is called for each line? I had a thought that the `-u` parameter to Bash might be related:

```
-u fd  Read input from file descriptor fd.
```

I've done some experiments to no avail. So how this option is supposed to be used may be another question.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 with Bash 4.3.48(1)-release.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't get rid of it and there's no reason to remove it anyway. This comes from bash checking whether the input is coming from a terminal (it calls [`isatty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html)). It doesn't actually use this information in your case, only when various options are passed. If you're curious about the details, read the source code (`read_builtin` function in `builtins/read.def`).

The fact that the `TCGETS` ioctl returns `ENOTTY` is how the application can tell that the input isn't a terminal. It's expected. Just because a function returns an error status doesn't mean that something is wrong.